# Redirecting a Form to it's Original Position in Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I have a Sharepoint Library which has Thousands of Forms. If i submit a form the pointer should point out that particular form which i have closed.

Comment: What do you mean by "the pointer "? do you wanna say that, the code has to show a pop saying the form has been submitted successfully? if yes,you can  SP.UI.notify API wthin the sp.js file.

Comment: You've already [asked the same question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165345).

Comment: scroll position should be on that form which i have closed

Comment: If particular form is enclosed with div then you can pass div ID in URL like "<YourURL>#<ID of Your form>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs some JavaScript on the ListView page

- On selection of a row store the row ID, as a cookie
- on load of the page load the cookie (id)
- execute `document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView()`

You could pass the info in the URL `Source=` part, but its more difficult to cover edge cases.

Maybe add a a check for `document.referer` so you only execute this when you return from a displaypage.

Please share the code in your question when you get this working